# How to get row count from a table using ruby capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, appium

In Java, we use:

```
WebElement tablename=driver.findElement(By.xpath("table_xpath"));

WebElement<List> rowcount=tablename.findelements(By.tagname("tr"));

sys(rowcount.size());
```

How to find row count in Ruby Capybara for above case?

Comment: Please reas http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with more detail. What you've tried, why it doesn't working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the elements matching a selector using `#all` so

```
page.all(:css, 'table tr').size
```

will count all the table rows in the page. If there are multiple tables and you want for a specific table you can increase the specificity of the CSS selector. You can also find the specific table and then call `all` on that

```
table = page.find(:css, 'table#my_table_id')
row_count = table.all(:css, 'tr').size
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that. is it possible to run a loop to collect all contents from each row and put it in an array? 
Say using row_count in for loop and getting each rows and its value and keep it in an array

Comment: It depends what you mean by contents, but whatever it is you don't really need row_count at all.  If you want the html of each row - it would be something like `table.all(:css, 'tr').map {|tr| tr['innerHTML']}`  if you mean the text content of each row it would be `table.all(:css, 'tr').map {|tr| tr.text}`  etc.. (note the :css is the default setting in Capybara so you may not actually need that parameter if you haven't changed the default)

Comment: Here is the thing. I have a table with 5 rows and 4 columns. in which first column belongs to numerical value. I want to collect all these values in an array and check whether the values are in ascending order or descending order. Please let me if you have any solution@tomwalpole @tom

Comment: ok - so you want the text contents of the first td of every row `table.all(:css, 'tr td:first-child').map {|td| td.text}`   - you could also do td.text.to_i if you want an array of integers or whatever instaed -- or rather than :css you can use :xpath and use indexes in your queries